# How to access elements in a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I made a neural network for regression purposes, but when I try to get the predictions, it shows something like this:

```
tf.Tensor 'sequential_5_5/dense_11/BiasAdd:0' shape=(1500, 1) dtype=float64
```

How can I access those 1500 values?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Why don't you take a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I think it could be useful for you and the community.

Answer (score 1):

A tensor is a state of data that describes its *type* (`int`, `float`...) and *shape* (one-dimensional array, two-dimensional and so on).
When you try to access a tensor, you basically get a description of its data-type, and not the data itself.
In order to see the value of the tensor you have, which is an array of length 1500 of floats, you need to use `tf.print()`, which will output the entire tensor array to the screen:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.range(10)
print(tensor)
tf.print(tensor)
```

output:

```
>>> tf.Tensor([0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

In order to extract a tensor's value into a numpy array do this:

```
tensor = tf.range(10)
array = tensor.numpy()
print(array)
```

output:

```
>>> [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: While the question is not completely clear, I'm not sure this answers the question being asked. In the title it, OP seems to want to know how to access  individual elements. This answer does not appear to address that. Please clarify, if I'm misunderstanding your answer, or the OP's question, or `edit` to add additional info.

Comment: @SherylHohman you are absolutely right. i edited my answer. as for you second comment, i added a way to extract the value of the tensor into an array, so if the question is how to iterate over a tensor'd value i think this solves this problem, too (since you can now iterate over it in a **for** loop)